# list all property names of controls based on condition in C#

Tags: c#, user-controls, controls, propertyinfo

I am trying to parse through all properties of all my controls (for example ascx files) from a certain page (this.Page.Controls) in order to obtain the name of the property that has a property value specified by me, for example - what is the name of the property that has the value "this is my header"? (it may very well be a textbox that contains this value).

The below returns this error:

> Cannot get inner content of  because the contents are not literal.
>     System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.get_InnerHtml()

not sure what it means or how to correct it.

```
 public String searchMethod(List<Control> listOfControls, String searchedValue)
        {
            String result = "";

            foreach (var control in listOfControls)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] properties = control.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof (string)) //added condition on this line *******************************
                    {
                        if (property.GetValue(control, null) != null)
                            if (property.GetValue(control, null).ToString().Contains("searched String"))
                            {
                                result = result + property.Name + "/" + property.GetValue(control, null) + "/";
                            }
                    }

                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I suppose it's stuck on a property that doesn't match the requirements, so why doesn't it simply move on to the next until it finds a good fit?
Apparently the property that gets it stuck is a `System.String Inner.Html`

PS. I've tested the listOfControls fed to the method and it's being generated correctly

Later Update:
Another method I am trying is:

```
public string Method1(List<Control> controlList, string propName)
        {
            string result = "";
            foreach (var control in controlList)
            {
                foreach(var prop in control.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        if((prop.GetValue(control,null).GetType()) == typeof(string))
                            if (prop.GetValue(control, null).ToString().Contains(propName))
                        result += prop.Name + "######";
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

but with this i get  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on line `if((prop.GetValue(control,null).GetType()) == typeof(string))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the documented behaviour of [`HtmlContainerControl.InnerHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml(v=vs.110).aspx) - in the "exceptions" section, it's documented that it will throw `HttpException` if:

> There is more than one HTML server control.
>   - or -
>   The HTML server control is not a System.Web.UI.LiteralControl or a System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl.

It sounds like the latter scenario is occurring in your case. The code doesn't "move on" because an exception is being thrown but not caught.

To be honest, I'd suggest being a bit pickier about the types of control that you check, and I'd probably use specific properties instead of just calling `ToString()`.

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet! I've been trying to apply your advice and came up with two version (at least) which I reedited my initial question with. Any thoughts? The second version seems much simpler and neater but throws an error...eventually. I'm not dexterous with syntax.

Comment: @Halle: Well that's going to fail if the property returns null. But it's unnecessary - if the property type is `string`, it can't return anything *other* than `string` or a null reference. More importantly, you're still going to be asking the value of the same property that caused your initial issue.

Comment: @Halle: If the property returns null, you're calling `GetType()` on a null reference - bang. The property that caused the problem (`HtmlContainer.InnerHtml`) isn't "of various types" - it's of type string. Basically, your change doesn't avoid the original problem, as far as I can see.

Comment: Could you please elaborate here? I understand that asking for the property value type is superfluous since I already know the property type. What is still unclear is "you're still going to be asking the value of the same property that caused your initial issue." My initial issue was that the property I was analysing was an object in itself, whereas now I restrict to only string types. But I still get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at the line where I try to grab the value of the property. Obviously? the value is null so can't be .ToString()-ed but how to solve that?

Comment: @Halle: No, that wasn't the problem. Look at the documentation for the property which is failing: it's a string property.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get that error if the control has controls inside of it. Do you need to search controls that may be inside of the controls in the list? If so you'd need to use recursion and keep drilling down into the controls (and any controls inside those) and only check `InnerHtml` on controls that don't contain other controls.

You can also simplify this a little by only checking the value when `property.PropertyType == typeof(string)`. You could also limit your search to just two properties - `Text` and `InnerHtml` if that's applicable.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott! I added this condition but get a "Cannot get inner content because the contents are not literal". Any thoughts on how to better this this? `if (property.PropertyType == typeof (string))` - you can see it in the edited question